# SOAP Message as a String Sent to End Point in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I have a String which is a SOAP message.

```
String message = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <xyz:Config xmlns:hal="http://example.com/xyz" applicationId="Client" conversationId="000" host="ENDPOINT">
</xyz:Config>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <PaymentRQ xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/4/0"
xmlns:common="http://www.iata.org/IATA/common/4/0">
            <PaymentDetails>
                  <PaymentDetail>
                        <common:PaymentCard CardNumber="1233444444444" CardType="100" ExpireDate="1120" SeriesCode="123">
                  </PaymentDetail>
            </PaymentDetails>
      </PaymentRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
";
```

I need to send this as a SOAP request to a local server running on 8080 
So, url would be http://localhost:8080/XYZService/xyz

Then fetch the SOAP response and read its values.

Kindly assist on how I can send the String as a SOAP message to the aforementioned url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may consider to throw away that string and start with Axis2 web-service. See http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/ and http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass null to SOAPAction if you don't have one.
for serverAddress pass serverIp + ServerPort(ex: 172.*.*.*:8088).

```
 public  String sendSoapRequest(String serverAdress, String message , String SOAPAction)
        {
            OutputStream httpOutputStream = null;
            byte[] byteArrayStream = message .getBytes();

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://"+serverAdress);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(byteArrayStream.length));
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
            try {
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            try {
                httpOutputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Write the content of the request to the outputstream of the HTTP Connection.
            try {
                httpOutputStream.write(byteArrayStream);
                httpOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader httpInputBuufferedReader = null;
            try {
                httpInputBuufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"IOException reading HTTP Input message ");
                return null;
            }

            //Write the SOAP message response to a String.
            StringBuilder returnOutputString = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                String line = "";
                while ((line = httpInputBuufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    returnOutputString.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOEception while reading HTTP input buffered reading");
            }
            return returnOutputString.toString();
        }
```

Comment: That worked like a breeze. You're a champ! Thank you so much Kiran.!